# Form is submit successfully if I copy csrf token from CodeIgniter form

Tags: codeigniter, csrf, csrf-protection

In codeigniter I have enabled csrf protection using `$config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;` in config.php file. The token is generate successfully in form and checking in server is it is also working normally. But my question is from inspection using Chrome I am copy whole form and also copy token so form is looks like:

```
<form action="http://localhost/Dropbox/project/admin/login/ajax_login" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="email" value="adasd">
    <input type="password" name="_password">
    <input type="hidden" name="csrf_test_name" value="cdff17389652a056eee94473661478f3">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

I am submit this form out of project it is submit successfully 1 time. It is give error on second time. I am copy new token and try again it is working 1 time. It is working 1 time it is normally behaviour or I am missing something on csrf token setting.

Answer (score 1):

Its an expected behaviour

if you want to change it just try to change your config file

```
$config['csrf_regenerate'] = false;
```

There is an excellent guide at Codeigniter.com who helps out with those kind of questions.

Just take a look at the [documentation](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/security.html).